# How can I achieve effective handdrawn line boil?

Tags: animation

I am trying to achieve a [deliberate line boil](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LineBoil) effect in a pose-by-pose animation. Similar, for example, to the effect achieved in [Dr Katz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Katz,_Professional_Therapist) (I know this particular example was done with [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squigglevision) rather than by hand).

My process is currently:

- hand draw a pose
- trace second version of pose (with some deliberate tracing badness to achieve line boil)
- scan both poses
- repeat for new pose
- for each pose, display for desired period, looping through two versions

However, the effect is not as I intended. There is often an illusion of movement, rather than a mostly-still pose with vibrant lines, and my intuitions about which lines to boil, and how to boil them, is sometimes just plain wrong. How can I instead achieve an effective line boil? (For example, do I need more than two boiled versions per frame? If so, how many? What line variations generally work, and are there any in particular to avoid? Should I avoid any simulated movement, including gestures and mouth movement?)

(The software I am using happens to be GIMP + Inkscape, but this is mostly for aligning / tweaking images, not the actual drawing or animation. I believe the answer lies in what I'm drawing rather than software, but I'm tentatively open to software related advice.)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, GIMP and Inkscape are primarily image and vectore manipulation tools. I think that you need to look at filters that add an extra layer of rendering to your work - have you by seen sketch and toon by cinema4d? they have a line randomness settings that adds that slighlt layer of imperfection to the renderings.

Helpful link - http://cinema-4d.wonderhowto.com/how-to/paint-line-weight-from-vector-art-using-cinema-4d-380473/